# Как в Python получить подсказку атрибутов дважды обёрнутой функции?

Tags: python, функции

Вот мой код:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
from typing import Any


class AsValuatedClass:
    def __init__(self, value=0) -> None:
        self._value = value
    
    def __call__(self, func) -> Any:
        class Valuated:
            def __init__(nested_self, value=0) -> None:
                nested_self.value = value
            
            def __call__(nested_self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
                print('All ', end='')
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        
        valuated = Valuated(value=self._value)
        update_wrapper(valuated, func)
        return valuated

@AsValuatedClass(10)
def func():
    print('Hello!')

func()
print(func.value)
```

Класс-обёртка инициализируется некоторыми параметрами и является callable объектом, который оборачивает функцию в класс с некоторыми атрибутами. Как мне получить подсветку синтаксиса в последней строке о том, что `func` содержит атрибут `value`? Ведь атрибут действительно существует.

Comment: у меня вот в стандартном `Python IDLE` подсказка всё показывает

Comment: Да вообще должно всё показывать. Я так понимаю, это что-то типа декоратора `wraps` оттуда же из `functools`.

Comment: 0_0 у меня не показывает(

Comment: Я использую `Pylance` в `VSCode`, если это имеет значение.

Answer (score 2):

Я удалил аннотации " `-> Any`" и это помогло. Похоже, Pylance воспринимает это как явное снятие типизации с возвращаемых объектов и, таким образом, игнорирует то, что ему уже известно о типе.